# Why does UIPinchGestureRecognizer couldn't recive Ended state?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have 4 gesture recognizers for 1 view.

```
- (void)createGestureRecognizers {
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerSingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleFingerSingleTap:)];
singleFingerSingleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.panelController.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerSingleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleFingerDoubleTap:)];
singleFingerDoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.panelController.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDoubleTap];

[singleFingerSingleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleFingerDoubleTap];

[singleFingerSingleTap release];
[singleFingerDoubleTap release];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[self.panelController.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
[self.panelController.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
[pinchGesture release];}
```

I need to process Ended state for UIPinchGestureRecognizer, but sometimes it has last state Changed, not Ended how it should be. Does anybody know why? I try to play with setDelaysTouchesEnded: but nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Pinch gesture is gesture of 2 fingers, so you sometimes one finger gets left on screen while other is already up. So, my advice is to handle `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` as well as `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`

Answer (score 0):

It's the same issue as the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`, it will trigger for each movement and will stop when you stop, but it won't tell you - hey the user removed the fingers, this movement is over.

This is because it's a continuous gesture, not a simple gesture.

You should handle `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` too.